# Função intrínseca para converter numérico para string

Tags: cobol

Estou a tentar saber se existe alguma função intrínseca do COBOL para converter um data numérico para string sem precisar usar a cláusula `REDEFINES`:

```
(    PIC S9(04) COMP)
```

Se sim, ela é mais onerosa que usa o `REDEFINES`?

Comment: COBOL é off-topic aqui... :D Brincadeirinha, hein pessoal? Não vão votar para fechar. Estava faltando diversidade mesmo!

Answer (score 10):

Não, não tem função intrínseca. `REDEFINES`, diretamente, não faz nada para você.

**Se quiser os números:**

```
01  O-CAMPO COMP PIC 9(4).

01  O-NUMERO PIC 9(4).

MOVE O-CAMPO TO O-NUMERO
DISPLAY O-NUMERO

X'000F' -- 0015
```

Note que, `PIC 9(4)` normalmente é `0-9999`. É possível utilizar todos os bits: faz `O-NUMERO PIC 9(5)`.

**Ou, em Hex:**

```
01  O-CAMPO COMP PIC 9(4).
01  FILLER REDEFINES O-CAMPO.
    05  O-CAMPO-HIGH PIC X. 
    05  O-CAMPO-LOW  PIC X. 

01  HEX-SUBSCRIPT COMP PIC 9(4) VALUE ZERO.
01  FILLER REDEFINES HEX-SUBSCRIPT.
    05  FILLER PIC X. 
    05  HEX-SUBSCRIPT-LOW PIC X.

01  HEX-IN-TEXT.
    05  HEX-IN-TEXT-HIGH PIC XX.
    05  HEX-IN-TEXT-LOW PIC XX.

01  HEX-DIGIT-TABLE.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '202122232425262728292A2B2C2D2E2F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '505152535455565758595A5B5C5D5E5F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '606162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '707172737475767778797A7B7C7D7E7F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '808182838485868788898A8B8C8D8E8F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE '909192939495969798999A9B9C9D9E9F'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE 'A0A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAABACADAEAF'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE 'B0B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BABBBCBDBEBF'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE 'C0C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CACBCCCDCECF'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE 'D0D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DADBDCDDDEDF'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE 'E0E1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAEBECEDEEEF'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(32) 
               VALUE 'F0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFBFCFDFEFF'.
01 FILLER REDEFINES HEX-DIGIT-TABLE.
    05 HEX-DIGITS  PIC X(2) OCCURS 256. 


    MOVE O-CAMPO-HIGH TO HEX-SUBSCRIPT-LOW
    MOVE HEX-DIGITS ( HEX-SUBSCRIPT + 1 ) TO HEX-IN-TEXT-HIGH
    MOVE O-CAMPO-LOW TO HEX-SUBSCRIPT-LOW
    MOVE HEX-DIGITS ( HEX-SUBSCRIPT + 1 ) TO HEX-IN-TEXT-LOW
    DISPLAY HEX-IN-TEXT

X'000F' -- 000F
```

COBOL é uma linguagem antiga. Ela não foi projetada para funções. Até 1989 ela não tinha funções. A partir de 1989 há uma lista limitada de funções intrínsecas (`intrinsic`). Elas são parte da linguagem e exclusivamente processadas pelo compilador (auxiliado por várias rotinas de tempo de execução, principalmente). Não existem funções definidas pelo usuário. Haverá mais funções intrínsecas na próxima versão do standard COBOL.

Funções definidas pelo usuário existirão em COBOL no futuro. Se quiser usá-las agora, veja o GNU COBOL (pesquise por ele no SourceForge).

Então, sinto muito, mas você vai ter de se virar sem funções.

REDEFINES não faz o que você parece achar que faz. Ele somente permite um outro "mapeamento" de uma armazenagem previsamente definida. O **conteúdo** da armazenagem não é afetado de maneira alguma, e retém o valor original até que você use o item do REDEFINES como **alvo** (*target*) de uma instrução.

Em COBOL, você tem que codar na mão. O que expliquei acima é uma maneira. Em termos de velocidade de execução e linhas de código de PROCEDURE, é uma boa maneira. Ela requer que uma tabela seja definida no WORKING-STORAGE (ou possivelmente no LOCAL-STORAGE).

O COBOL (padrão) não pode manipular bytes individuais em binário. A técnica é redefinir (REDEFINES) um um campo binário de dois bytes com um VALUE nicial de ZERO, e então colocar um byte individual no byte de menor ordem, e usar o campo binário como *subscript*. Como você quer converter X'00' para "00", e zero não é um subscript válido, mas precisa ser a primeira entrada da tabela, você precisa deslocar a referência do subscript em um ( HEX-SUBSCRIPT + 1 ). Se preferir, você pode usar ADD/COMPUTE para incrementar o valor do subscript em um.

Answer (score 1):

Tendo duas váriaveis:

```
01 ALPHA-NUMERICO PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
01 NUMERICO       PIC 9(10) VALUE 1234567890.
```

Um simples comando `MOVE NUMERICO TO ALPHA-NUMERICO` já converte em string, sem necessidade de função.

Há também a opção de declarar a variável numérica como filha.

```
01 ALPHA-NUMERICO.
  03 NUMERICO       PIC 9(10) VALUE 1234567890.
```

Dessa forma, a variável `ALPHA-NUMERICO` contém o valor de `NUMERICO` na forma de string.

Comment: O COBOL não tem strings. A "conversão" que você está propondo contém nenhuma conversão de todo, um campo numérico USAGE DISPLAY sem sinal tem as configurações-bit exatas como um campo alfanumérico USAGE DISPLAY que contém o valor numérico equivalente, conforme o seu segundo exemplo mostra. O Asker tem um campo binário, e parece querer a representação de texto de seu valor expresso em hexadecimal. No entanto, o Asker nunca voltou, então quem sabe ...

Comment: Não reparei que o campo numérico é binário... nesse caso, meu exemplo realmente não se encaixa. E não dá pra converter diretamente, nem mesmo com `REDEFINES`, devido ao sinal. Acredito que a intenção dele seria ter algo como "+1234" em um campo alphanumérico.

Comment: Nós talvez nunca se sabe o que foi realmente queria :-)